# PJ344K help to identify please

Tags: identification

Transil probably, but google, vendors do no know this part[image]

Comment: Judging by the reference designator, it is probably a transient suppressor diode. That's all I can make of it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 160V transient suppressor diode [1SMB170AT3] from On Semi (https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1SMB5.0AT3-D-108677.pdf)

[image]

but it doesn't clarify the K shown in on the diode on the picture.